# How do I modify a TextView of MainActivity from an AsyncTask?

Tags: android, android-asynctask

I'm writing a chat application, which has 2 processes (Get and Send). They are written inside MainActivity and work like this:

```
Send: //Called when button is pressed
(1) Get String from editText into MSG
(2) Run AsyncTask_SEND(MSG).executeOnExecutor(...) to send
    (this procedure avoids internet calls at main thread (NetworkOnMainThreadException))
(3) TextView.setText( TextView.getText() + "Local : " + MSG + "\n" );


Get: //Called at onCreate
Run AsyncTask_GET().executeOnExecutor(...) to get messages.
It's doInBackground works like this:
|    (1) Declare String MSG
|    (2) While client still has messages to send (kind of infinite loop):
|    |    (2.1) Get client's next line into MSG
|    |    (2.2) TextView.setText( TextView.getText() + "Remote : " + MSG + "\n" );
```

The problem is step (2.2) from Get obviously doesn't work.

Instead of it, I'm using Log.d("Remote", MSG) to print remote messages at LogCat console.

My question is: Given this TextView is placed at MainActivity (and the AsyncTask_GET is an independent class), how do I modify this TextView from the AsyncTask_GET ?

Comment: You have two choices, first in the post execute method. Second pass your activity instance in constructor an then in the doinbackground method run to a runnable as adam said. i rexolmend The first choice .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Async task got buildin method just for that. Its called onProgressUpdate, adn it runs on ui thread.

```
private class DownloadFilesTask extends AsyncTask<URL, String, Long> {
     protected Long doInBackground(URL... urls) {

             publishProgress("hello from async task"); 
            // you call it just like this, but remember its array

         }
         return totalSize;
     }

     protected void onProgressUpdate(String... string) {

      textView.settext(string[0]); // and here you set the text

     }

     protected void onPostExecute(Long result) {
         showDialog("Downloaded " + result + " bytes");
     }
 }
```

Comment: it worked!! thanks @Adam Fręśko :)
I gave the mainactivity textview to the constructor of the asynctask and updated it successfully at the onProgressUpdate.

Answer (score 3):

If it's independant class, you can add a constructor to your AsyncTask class and send a TextView to it, then you can change its text in `onPostExecute()` method like:

```
public class GetMsg extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {
    private TextView msg;

    public GetMsg(TextView msg){
        this.msg = msg;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        // Change the text of msg TextView
        msg.setText("Add your text here");
}
```

and to call this you just add your TextView inside the constructor like

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textview); // your textview
new GetMsg(tv).execute();
```

Comment: The Best Answer, Thank You